# Program type already present: org.bouncycastle.LICENSE

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Program type already present: org.bouncycastle.LICENSE

Hello Everyone Hope you are doing well.

Here is my question : We are using Two different types of Module library in one project but the scenario is We are getting compilation error of Program type already present: org.bouncycastle.LICENSE & we didn't get where it is. So here we want a solution for how can we fix this issue without deleting or removing any module in our project ? We use this library in one of our module - bcprov-jdk15on-157.jar
We got while run this issue More than one file was found with OS independent path 'org/bouncycastle/x509/CertPathReviewerMessages_de.properties'

```
   packagingOptions {
         exclude 'org.bouncycastle.LICENSE'
         exclude 'LICENSE'
         exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
         exclude 'META-             
         INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'
         exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
  }

  configurations {
         compile.exclude module: 'org.bouncycastle'
         compile.exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'
  }
```

This is my gradle file

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
  android {
       compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
         applicationId "xxxxx"
         minSdkVersion 19
         targetSdkVersion 27
         versionCode 2
         versionName "1.1"
         multiDexEnabled true
         testInstrumentationRunner 
           "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
       release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
        'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'org.bouncycastle.LICENSE'
    exclude 'LICENSE'
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/services/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory'
    exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
}


configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'org.bouncycastle'
   compile.exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson'

}

}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  /* implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib- 
   jdk7:$kotlin_version"*/
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
   implementation 'xml-security:xmlsec:1.3.0'
   implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
   implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
   implementation 'com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker:library:1.9'
   implementation 'com.moos:Material-ProgressView:1.0.6'
   implementation 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
   implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
   /* implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'*/
   implementation 'com.github.ravindu1024:android-loadingdialog:1.0.3'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-              
   core:3.0.2'
   implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
   implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.0'
   annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.0'
   implementation project(':framework-release')
   implementation project(':aepscore')
   implementation project(':aepslibrary-release')
   implementation project(':fingpay')
   }
```

This is my Error log

```
         org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for 
        task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
at  
   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter. 
   executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
at 
  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter. 
   execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
at 
  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution. 
  OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter 
  .execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter. 
  execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution. 
   ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute 
  (ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter. 
   execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
at 
  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter 
  .execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFileProperties 
   TaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
at 
   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter. 
   execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution. 
   ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute 
  (ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at 
  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter 
 .execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter. 
   execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at 
  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter. 
  execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.
  execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$ 
  EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ 
  RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute 
  (DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$ 
  RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute 
  (DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor. 
  execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor. 
  run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$ 
  EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$ 
  EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ 
  TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ 
  TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ 
  TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ 
  TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan. 
  execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan. 
    executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$                        
    TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecord 
    Failures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1. 
   run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker 
   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run 
   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$Managed 
   ThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: More 
than one file was found with OS independent path 
'org/bouncycastle/x509/CertPathReviewerMessages_de.properties'
at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms. 
lambda$acceptOnlyOne$2(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:75)
at com.android.builder.merge.StreamMergeAlgorithms. 
lambda$select$3(StreamMergeAlgorithms.java:100)
at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMergerOutputs$1. 
create(IncrementalFileMergerOutputs.java:86)
at com.android.builder.merge.DelegateIncrementalFileMergerOutput. 
create(DelegateIncrementalFileMergerOutput.java:61)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms. 
MergeJavaResourcesTransform$1.create(MergeJavaResourcesTransform.java:379)
at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMerger. 
updateChangedFile(IncrementalFileMerger.java:221)
at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMerger. 
mergeChangedInputs(IncrementalFileMerger.java:190)
at com.android.builder.merge.IncrementalFileMerger. 
merge(IncrementalFileMerger.java:77)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms. 
MergeJavaResourcesTransform.transform 
(MergeJavaResourcesTransform.java:411)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2. 
call(TransformTask.java:239)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2. 
call(TransformTask.java:235)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record 
(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask. 
transform(TransformTask.java:230)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor562.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke 
(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory. 
IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction. 
execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction. 
execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActions 
TaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor 
$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute 
(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor 
$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute 
(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor. 
execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor. 
run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActions 
TaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter. 
executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
... 33 more
```

Comment: did you get any solution

Comment: did you get any solution

Comment: Have any one got the solution?